# Having problems with my array, don't know what to put after the else.(updated)

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, if-statement

I think the problem is in the if statement as i'm trying not to use document.getElementById. I'm not really a coding expert just do it for fun
can someone more experienced help me, never really dealt with if statements and path arrays
*also think that the problem might be the html as changeImage(this).

```
function changeImage(image)
{
var patharray = image.src.split('/');
var name = patharray[patharray.length -1];
if (name == "FlyingHigh.png") 
{
.src = "FlyingHigh.png";
}
else 
{
.src = "FlyingHigh2.png"
}
}

<img src="FlyingHigh.png" onclick = "changeImage(this)" </img>
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: _What_ is the problem? What happens? What do you wish to happen instead? What is `.src` supposed to do?

Comment: `.src = "FlyingHigh.png";` isn't valid JavaScript.

`.` is used to invoke a method on an object. You've left out the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you pass in `this` in the `onclick` - reference the parameter it is assigned to in the function (`image`)

```
function changeImage(image)
{
    var patharray = image.src.split('/');
    var name = patharray[patharray.length -1];
    if (name == "FlyingHigh.png") 
    {
        image.src = "FlyingHigh.png";
    }
    else 
    {
        image.src = "FlyingHigh2.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: @naomik -- You're the first one to ever comment about Samus! +1

Answer (score 0):

There is two problems with the code:

- You need to specify `image.src`, not just `.src`.
- When you find one image you want to set the other, not the same one.

Adjusted code:

```
function changeImage(image) {
  var patharray = image.src.split('/');
  var name = patharray[patharray.length -1];
  if (name == "FlyingHigh.png") {
    image.src = "FlyingHigh2.png";
  } else  {
    image.src = "FlyingHigh.png"
  }
}
```